# create grid with turtles in python

Tags: python-2.7, grid, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is the current code I have. It only makes the vertical lines of the grid. I need help making the horizontal lines. I'm not sure how to go about with the directions.

```
import math
import turtle
GRID_SIZE = 600

sub_divisions = int(input("Enter the number of sub-divisions: "))

cell_size = GRID_SIZE / sub_divisions


#print subdivisions

scn = turtle.Screen()

dan = turtle.Turtle()
dan.pu()
dan.forward(GRID_SIZE/2)
dan.right(90)
dan.forward(GRID_SIZE/2)
dan.pd()

for i in range(4):
    dan.right(90)
    dan.forward(GRID_SIZE)
    
    
for z in range(1,sub_divisions):
    dan.pu()
    dan.goto(-GRID_SIZE/2,GRID_SIZE/2)
    dan.pd()
    dan.left(90)
    dan.forward(cell_size * z)
    dan.right(90)
    dan.forward(GRID_SIZE)
    





scn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Create a second `for` loop just like the vertical but for horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

If you can draw your vertical lines in *relative* terms, not *absolute* terms where you always go back to a fixed point like `dan.goto(-GRID_SIZE/2,GRID_SIZE/2)`, then drawing horizontal lines is simply a mater of rerunning the *same* code, changing the turtle starting point and orientation:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

GRID_SIZE = 600

sub_divisions = int(input("Enter the number of sub-divisions: "))

cell_size = GRID_SIZE / float(sub_divisions)  # force float for Python 2

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-GRID_SIZE/2, GRID_SIZE/2)
turtle.pendown()

angle = 90

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE)
    turtle.right(angle)

for _ in range(2):
    for _ in range(1, sub_divisions):
        turtle.forward(cell_size)
        turtle.right(angle)
        turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE)
        turtle.left(angle)

        angle = -angle

    turtle.forward(cell_size)
    turtle.right(angle)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Note how the turtle is always moving forward, not backing up over something it has just drawn.